# Python Append items to dictionary in a loop

Tags: python

I am trying to append values to a dictionary inside a loop, but somehow it's only appending one of the values. I recreated the setup using the same numbers I am dynamically getting.

The output from "print(vertex_id_from_shell)" is "{0: [4], 1: [12], 2: [20]}". I need to keep the keys, but add the remaining numbers to the values.

Thanks.

```
shells = {0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], 1: [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], 2: [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]}
uvsID = [0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 9, 8, 1, 10, 11, 3, 12, 0, 2, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 16, 18, 19, 19, 18, 20, 21, 21, 20, 22, 23, 15, 24, 25, 16, 26, 14, 17, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 31, 30, 32, 33, 33, 32, 34, 35, 35, 34, 36, 37, 29, 38, 39, 30, 40, 28, 31, 41]
vertsID = [0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 1, 0, 1, 7, 5, 3, 6, 0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 11, 10, 10, 11, 13, 12, 12, 13, 15, 14, 14, 15, 9, 8, 9, 15, 13, 11, 14, 8, 10, 12, 16, 17, 19, 18, 18, 19, 21, 20, 20, 21, 23, 22, 22, 23, 17, 16, 17, 23, 21, 19, 22, 16, 18, 20]


vertex_id_from_shell = {}

for shell in shells:
    selection_shell = shells.get(shell)
    
    #print(selection_shell)
    
    for idx, item in enumerate(selection_shell):
        if item in uvsID:
            uv_index =  uvsID.index(item)
            vertex_ids = vertsID[uv_index]
            vertex_id_from_shell[shell] =  [  ( vertex_ids ) ]
    
print(vertex_id_from_shell)
#{0: [4], 1: [12], 2: [20]} 

#desired result
{0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 7, 0, 1, 7, 5, 6, 4], 1: [8, 9, 11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14, 9, 8, 15, 13, 14, 12], 2: [16, 17, 19, 18, 21, 20, 23, 22, 17, 16, 23, 21, 22, 20]}
```

Comment: Use `for shell, selection_shell in shells.items():` so you don't need to call `get()`.

Comment: Could you show what the desired result is?

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate()`? You never use `idx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `vertex_id_from_shell[shell]` to a new list, containing only one item every time. Instead, you should append to it.
But first, of course that list needs to exist, so you should check and create it if it doesn't already exist.

```
shells = {0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], 1: [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], 2: [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]}
uvsID = [0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 9, 8, 1, 10, 11, 3, 12, 0, 2, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 16, 18, 19, 19, 18, 20, 21, 21, 20, 22, 23, 15, 24, 25, 16, 26, 14, 17, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 31, 30, 32, 33, 33, 32, 34, 35, 35, 34, 36, 37, 29, 38, 39, 30, 40, 28, 31, 41]
vertsID = [0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 1, 0, 1, 7, 5, 3, 6, 0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 11, 10, 10, 11, 13, 12, 12, 13, 15, 14, 14, 15, 9, 8, 9, 15, 13, 11, 14, 8, 10, 12, 16, 17, 19, 18, 18, 19, 21, 20, 20, 21, 23, 22, 22, 23, 17, 16, 17, 23, 21, 19, 22, 16, 18, 20]


vertex_id_from_shell = {}

for shell in shells:
    selection_shell = shells.get(shell)
    
    #print(selection_shell)
    
    for idx, item in enumerate(selection_shell):
        if item in uvsID:
            uv_index =  uvsID.index(item)
            vertex_ids = vertsID[uv_index]

            # if the list does not exist, create it
            if shell not in vertex_id_from_shell:
                vertex_id_from_shell[shell] = []

            # append to list
            vertex_id_from_shell[shell].append(vertex_ids)
    
print(vertex_id_from_shell)
# {0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 7, 5, 6, 4],
#  1: [8, 9, 11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14, 9, 8, 15, 13, 14, 12],
#  2: [16, 17, 19, 18, 21, 20, 23, 22, 17, 16, 23, 21, 22, 20]}
```

Comment: @johancc thanks, you should probably check out the answer by @ Barmar too, it's a better implementation. it's doing the same thing but it's easier to write

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting `vertex_id_from_shell[shell]` each time through the loop, not appending to it.

Use `collections.defaultdict()` to automatically create the dictionary elements with an empty list if necessary, then you can append.

```
from collections import defaultdict

vertex_id_from_shell = defaultdict(list)

for shell, selection_shell in shells.items():
    for item in selection_shell:
        if item in uvsID:
            uv_index =  uvsID.index(item)
            vertex_ids = vertsID[uv_index]
            vertex_id_from_shell[shell].append(vertex_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using parts from your answer too.